# How to change .jenkins auto-generated on slave node to another path

Tags: jenkins

I'm a newfish on Jenkins. I have a slave node which has disk quota limitation on home/myaccount, however I found there're .jenkins generated on my slave node when Jenkins' Jobs run on this node. After some runs, the disk quota has exceed its limitation, is there any method to change the .jenkins not on my home directory but in other path?

Thanks!

Comment: .jenkins stays on /home/myaccount

Comment: You can set the remote root directory to something else when configuring slave node in Jenkins. That way all your jobs will run within that dir.

Comment: it seems doesn't work. I have tried to change my remote root directory from my home to another place before I submit this question. However, it seems job still creates some temporary files mainly .jar file in /home/myaccount/.jenkins.